# Populating bridge table with conditions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a bridge table **trajectory_detail** that I am supposed to populate with millions of records from the corresponding parent tables. The problem is that every value from parent table **trajectory_id** is supposed to have at least 3 values of **activity_id** from parent table activities and the date for all these values must be less than 3 months apart.

```
            create table medical_trajectory
        (
            traject_id int identity(1,1) not null,
            patient_id int not null,
            PRIMARY KEY(traject_id)
        
        )
    
        create table activities (
        activity_id int identity(1,1) not null,
        name varchar(256) not null,
        PRIMARY KEY(activity_id)
    )
    
        create table trajectory_detail ( -- bridge table
            traject_id int not null,
            activity_id int not null,
            date_performed date not null,
            FOREIGN KEY(traject_id) REFERENCES medical_trajectory(traject_id),
            FOREIGN KEY(activity_id) REFERENCES activities(activity_id)
)
```

The desired outcome would look like this:

[image]

I have somehow managed to resolve this using nested while loops but the performance is just terrible and I am kinda stuck and would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Hi Ben, welcome to the site!  For this question to be answerable, it really needs to have the table definition (as `CREATE TABLE` statements) and some sample starting data (as `INSERT` statements). Without the extra detail, getting to the desired outcome in a way that is helpful to you (and other readers) isn't really possible.

Comment: The artistID is not in the Album table. How can you know which album was made by which artist ? 
Your table definition is either not valid or you excluded part of the definition (As you show Date as an expected column in the result but there is no date column in any of your table). 
Please provide the full table definition and some example of the data that each table contains

Comment: Yes, you are right, I have just included this table definition as an example that might be easier to understand. I have updated it so you can see what real full table definition looks like. Sorry for the confusion, it's my first time asking for help here.

Comment: This would be relatively straightforward without the requirement for 3 or more distinct activities AND 3 or more activities within three months.  *Almost* have it figured out.

Comment: The problem isn't very clear at the moment. First of all, what do you mean by "supposed to have at least 3 values"? Are you picking those values arbitrarily and choose, say, three for some `trajectory_id` and five for another? Or is there some rule regarding which activities to choose? In which case what should happen if a trajectory has fewer than three activities? Also, where are the date values supposed to come from? Do you just generate them or is there an actual date column that you forgot to mention that provides the dates?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume there is a table with the activities and dates, and you are only inserting the conforming records into your table.  I'm going to call that `data_source`.

So we need to do a few things here:

1. Establish intervals of three months around `traject_id` for each `date_performed`.
2. Find the number of activities that occurred within those intervals, and a distinct count of `activity_id`.
3. Remove intervals that do not contain at least three distinct activities.
4. Ensure the intervals do not overlap then join to the original data.

So here goes:

```
WITH traj_interval AS
(
  SELECT
    interval.traject_id
   ,interval.start_date
   ,CASE
      WHEN interval.end_date < LEAD(interval.start_date,1,'9999-12-31') OVER (PARTITION BY interval.traject_id ORDER BY interval.start_date) THEN interval.end_date
      ELSE DATEADD(DAY,-1,LEAD(interval.start_date) OVER (PARTITION BY interval.traject_id ORDER BY interval.start_date))
    END AS end_date
  FROM
    (
      SELECT DISTINCT
        traject_id
       ,date_performed AS start_date
       ,DATEADD(MONTH,3,date_performed) AS end_date
      FROM
        data_source
    ) interval
  INNER JOIN
    data_source data_source
      ON data_source.traject_id = interval.traject_id
           AND data_source.date_performed >= interval.start_date
           AND data_source.date_performed <= interval.end_date
  GROUP BY
    interval.traject_id
   ,interval.start_date
   ,interval.end_date
  HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT data_source.activity_id) >= 3
)
SELECT
  data_source.traject_id
 ,data_source.activity_id
 ,data_source.date_performed
FROM
  data_source data_source
INNER JOIN
  traj_interval traj_interval
    ON traj_interval.traject_id = data_source.traject_id
         AND traj_interval.start_date <= data_source.date_performed
         AND traj_interval.end_date >= data_source.date_performed
```

So this handles gaps and overlapping intervals, which is the major headache from before.

This does not make the prettiest execution plan, but it has to be faster than performing loops.